# Return all user profile except current users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am iterating over all user profiles to get their country. I wish not to include the current user's profile. If I have a total of 10 users, I want only 9 user's country:

```
# helper function
def method_name
  Profile.all.select do |m|
   n = m.country.class == String # Because most countries will be nil. A shorter way to not include nil profiles?
   return n.reject! {|x| x == current_user.profile.user_id }
  end
end
```

The method above should return all user's profile except for the current user.

The error I got is

> undefined method `reject!' for false:FalseClass

The reason? In my views I could:

```
<%= method_name.map do |p| p.country end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `n = m.country.class == String` sets `n` to `true` or `false`, thefore the next line fails, because you try to call `reject! {|x| x == current_user.profile.user_id }` on that boolean value.

One way to solve the problem might be to fix your code like this:

```
def method_name
  Profile.all.select do |p|
    p.country.present? && p != current_user.profile
  end
end
```

Another way - and my preferred one - would be to only load matching record from the database:

```
def method_name
  Profile.where.not(user_id: current_user.id).where.not(country: nil)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware of using Profile.all here, because you will potentially use a lot of memory instantiating a profile object for every row in your database.

I think the best way to do this is to create a method within your Profile model, which performs the query, and uses **pluck()** to return an array containing just the countries you want.

```
def self.countries_except_for(user)

  where.not(user_id: user.id, country: nil).pluck(:country)

end
```

Now you can just call:

```
Profile.countries_except(current_user)
```

To get the array of countries. This approach is much more efficient than looping through as in your question.